# JS/HTML/CSS animation game -- only select animations freeze

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following a tutorial on using vanilla JS/HTML/CSS to create a 2D animation game. I'm currently stuck, however, because some of my "spiders" become stuck in their path, and won't move—and some of them do so out of the screen such that their webs are visible and won't disappear. I went back to the tutorial's code and tried to find any differences in the code, but couldn't find any. I've been playing around with the vertical values, as well as the part where I deal with animation frames, but couldn't fix the bug.

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 800;

    class Game {
        constructor(ctx, width, height) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.enemies = [];
            this.enemyInterval = 400;
            this.enemyTimer = 0;
            this.enemyTypes = ["worm", "ghost", "spider"];
        }
        update(deltaTime) {
            this.enemies = this.enemies.filter(object => !object.markedForDeletion);
            if (this.enemyTimer > this.enemyInterval) {
                this.#addNewEnemy();
                this.enemyTimer = 0;
            } else {
                this.enemyTimer += deltaTime; 
            }
            this.enemies.forEach(object => object.update(deltaTime));
        }
        draw() {
            this.enemies.forEach(object => object.draw(this.ctx));
        }
        #addNewEnemy() {
            const randomEnemy = this.enemyTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.enemyTypes.length)];
            if (randomEnemy === "worm") this.enemies.push(new Worm(this));
            else if (randomEnemy === "ghost") this.enemies.push(new Ghost(this));
            else if (randomEnemy === "spider") this.enemies.push(new Spider(this));
            // this.enemies.sort(function(a, b) {
            //     return a.y - b.y;
            // });
        }
    }

    class Enemy {
        constructor(game) {
            this.game = game;
            this.markedForDeletion = false;
            this.frameX = 0;
            this.maxFrame = 5;
            this.frameInterval = 100;
            this.frameTimer = 0;
        }
        update(deltaTime) {
            this.x -= this.vx * deltaTime;
            if (this.x < 0 - this.width) this.markedForDeletion = true;
            if (this.frameTimer > this.frameInterval) {
                if (this.frameX < this.maxFrame) this.frameX++;
                else this.frameX = 0;
                this.frameTimer = 0;
            } else {
                this.frameTimer += deltaTime;
            }
        }
        draw(ctx) {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.frameX * this.spriteWidth, 0, this.spriteWidth, this.spriteHeight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    class Spider extends Enemy{
        constructor() {
            super(game);
            this.spriteWidth = 310;
            this.spriteHeight = 175;
            this.width = this.spriteWidth/2;
            this.height = this.spriteHeight/2;
            this.x = Math.random() * this.game.width;
            this.y = 0 - this.height;
            this.image = spider;
            this.vx = 0;
            this.vy = Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.1;
            this.maxLength = Math.random() * this.game.height * 0.7;
        }
        update(deltaTime) {
            super.update(deltaTime);
            if (this.y < 0 - this.height * 1.5) this.markedForDeletion = true;
            this.y += this.vy * deltaTime;
            if (this.y > this.maxLength) this.vy *= -1;
        }
        draw(ctx) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.width/2, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.width/2, this.y + 10);
            ctx.stroke();
            super.draw(ctx);
        }
    }

    const game = new Game(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    let lastTime = 1;
    function animate(timeStamp) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime;
        lastTime = timeStamp;
        game.update(deltaTime);
        game.draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate(0);
})
```

```css
#canvas1 {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Enemy Variety</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <img src="images/enemy_worm.png" id="worm">
    <img src="images/enemy_ghost.png" id="ghost">
    <img src="images/enemy_spider.png" id="spider">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Apologies for the current snippet not working. I assume it's because I can't find a way to upload the image with the code, but I'm attaching it here for reference: https://www.frankslaboratory.co.uk/downloads/enemy_spider.png (Warning: this image is only to be used for educational purposes)

Comment: Can you add a sample of what the animation should look like? Also, add other images used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the `draw()` method inside the `Spider` class, you must call `super.draw()` *before* running other code:

```
    draw(ctx) {
        super.draw(ctx);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.width/2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.width/2, this.y + 10);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```